# Can't debug MAUI app that is also installed

Tags: maui, .net-maui, maui-windows

I have built an app using .NET MAUI (targeting Widows and Mac), and gone through the process of publishing it as a self-signed MSIX package. I then installed the app on my dev machine using the MSIX. This all worked as expected.

On returning to my app project in Visual Studio to work on it further, when I try to debug the app, Visual Studio displays the following message:

> The app "AD79D964-7DE4-44D0-B604-69F7925DDE60_0.3.0.0_x64_qcfv
> hv4r9mcdr is already installed on this machine. If you continue with
> the current deployment, the existing app will be uninstalled and the
> app's current state will be deleted. Are you sure you want to
> continue? Yes / No

I assume that this is caused by an ID clash between my development version and the installed/published version, but I'm not sure what to do about this, and it seems surprising to me that an installed app and an app running in the VS debugger would conflict in this way.

My question: Is there a way to separate them as far as Windows and VS are concerned?

(To be clear: I'm not trying to debug an instance of the installed, published, app. I'm just trying to debug some post-publish development changes.)

(Visual Studio Version 17.3.0 Preview 6.0, .net 6.0, Windows 10 Pro x64)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and it seems surprising to me that an installed app and an app running in the VS debugger would conflict in this way.

The app will be deployed when debugging as if it is an installed app, that is why you see the clash.

The obvious way to get around it is just press Yes and it will replace the installed version and you can test your changes. Whenever you're done you can always go back to the store version if that's what you need by simply installing it again.

If that's not something you want, you might try this, but note I haven't tested this, it's just something that came to mind. In the csproj file find the GUID that makes up your package name/ID, copy and paste it and add conditions to the nodes where one ID is the one you release to the store so only add that when you do a release configuration build and set the other one to != configuration build (or == debug if you only use debug anyway) and change that value a little bit.

Now it will deploy as a separate app. So it should look more or less like:

```xml
<ApplicationIdGuid Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Release'">00000000-059B-4FBC-9D92-476E59FB937A</ApplicationIdGuid>
<ApplicationIdGuid Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">1F9C3A44-059B-4FBC-9D92-476E59FB937A</ApplicationIdGuid>
```

You could do the same for the application name to be able to make a distinction from that easier as well.

Comment: Thanks - that seems to work. I understood that the problem was caused by the ID/guid clash, but I didn't realise I could use a Condition attribute on the <ApplicationIdGuid> element.

Comment: Coming from .net framework development, deploying an app under development as if it were installed seems strange to me. I guess this is a UWP constraint/feature.

Comment: This is indeed because of the way how Windows apps are sandboxed and deployed :)